# Google Maps APIv2 Authentication failure

Tags: android, google-maps, authentication, key

The error:

```
08-15 12:59:17.435: E/Google Maps Android API(14665): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

The Google Console:

[image: google console]

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cefetmgrdctcc.sgtp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.cefetmgrdctcc.sgtp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.cefetmgrdctcc.sgtp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Hidden key"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.cefetmgrdctcc.sgtp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The layout of the map control:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googlemap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I've imported the Google Play Services into my project and marked on the Google API Console Services list "Google Maps API v2", "Google Maps API v3" and "Google Maps Android API v2", however it seems my Map Fragment is still not being able to authenticate.

Map Fragment is just a blank grey square on the middle of the screen, any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi I was just having this exact same problem. I tried everything the docs said but nothing seemed to work.

The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling and reinstalling my application (not even rebooting worked) because apparently if you make one mistake on the configuration the system caches the failed authentication and your maps won't work even after fixing your configuration.

So try following the docs and guides on configuring Google Maps Api on Android but every time you change something on your configuration uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I uninstalled the apk using the default Applications manager in the phone's settings and rebooted the testing device. Really weird error it was though.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Used the wrong google-play-service-lib, and app won't authenticate with the new lib until I uninstall the app on my device. No need  to reboot in my case though, just un-install, and re-install worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for helping me not to waste another 3 hours.

Comment: You deserve a cookie, Thanks Jucas

Answer (score 1):

If you are running application on a device,experiencing the same issue and had no luck any other solutions.

- make sure the installed  google-play services is the latest one.
- make sure the device date and time is correct as well

  http://www.techkhoji.com/no-connection-retry-google-play-store/

  > Google Play Services sync with their master servers to send and
  >   receive data, to do this your device time and date should be correctly
  >   set

Check if other applications depend on google-play services such as Play Store are working.If they are having trouble with connecting to servers ("NO CONNECTION, RETRY") even when the internet connection is available one of the  above points could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I regenerated API key and updated in google console, its working fine